# Dwarf Alberta Spruce Winter Burn

Tags: plant-health, tree-care, conifers, spruces

I have a Dwarf Alberta Spruce which is showing signs of worse-than-normal winter burn. Not only have the needles on the south side of the tree browned, but the new buds on that side also appear to have died. I've heard that this was caused by our severe winter - when the trees should have started taking up water, the frost line was still 5 feet deep, and the plants dried out.

Is there anything I can do to help the tree along other than just wait? Pruning will not help, correct? Usually I have some winter burn, but the new buds remain green and by early summer the tree is as beautiful as ever.

Answer (score 2):

I was just looking for similar information when I ran across this link from Virginia Tech on [managing winter injury to trees and shrubs](http://pubs.ext.vt.edu/426/426-500/426-500.html).

I suggest reading the link but in summary, prune obviously dead branches, water thoroughly and fertilize to promote new growth.